# GridView aspx c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an application im developing in Visual Studio 2019.
I have a gridView that is set to autogenerate columns.
The grid has pagination, which I do not want so I have set the `AllowPaging="false" PagerSettings-Visible="false"`

However, this now only returns me the first page of rows in the datagrid, where I want it to show me all the rows. I have set the height to auto but it still wont show all rows. Its like the visibility of the paging is hidden but the functionally is still there.

This is the code aspx code:

```
<cc1:GridView ID="tgvCallDetailSummary"
    runat="server" 
    Style="position: absolute; top:25px; left: 5px; height:auto " 
    AllowPaging="false" 
    PagerSettings-Visible="false" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
    SqlStatement="" 
    StaticTableWidth="0" 
    OnPreRender="tgvCallDetailSummary_PreRender">
  <Columns>                                    
  </Columns> 
</cc1:GridView>
```

Comment: How many rows is it showing? Are you sure the data source has more data than is being shown in the grid?

Comment: yes there is 13 rows of data but grid is only showing 10. Fixed the issue by increasing pagesize to 20

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix the issue
with adding pagesize=20